# How to pause the entire code for 1 second in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code an evolutionary neural network for the game snake. I already coded the neural network part and now I'd like to output the game of the best individual of every generation. For that I'm using the drawing library p5.js (https://p5js.org/).

In my code I am running a loop in where a new generation based on the last generation is created. Each individual of the generation will have to play the game and that is how they are rated. Now I want the best individual to be outputted after I let every individual play once.

Between each outputted turn of the game of the best individual I want the code to wait 500 milliseconds. How do I achieve that?

Here is the code I've already tried but here it only outputed the board after the last turn of each generation:

```
async function start() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        population.createNewGeneration();

        let bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns; //Array of boards      
        for (let turn = 0; turn < bestGameTurns.length; turn++) {
            let board = bestGameTurns[turn];
            drawBoard(board);
            let p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            await p;

            function drawBoard(board) {
                //Draw the board using p5.js rect()'s
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Another version but the waiting didn't work here:

```
let i = 0;
setInterval(async () => {
    population.createNewGeneration();
    console.log(i, population.avgFitness);

    let bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns; //Array of boards  
    for (let turn = 0; turn < bestGameTurns.length; turn++) {
        let board = bestGameTurns[turn];
        drawBoard(board);
        let p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        await p;

        function drawBoard(board) {
            //Draw the board using p5.js rect()'s
        }
    }
    i++;
}, 1);
```

Comment: You have to convert the for loop into small steps then call each steps after 500ms. Note that the code you wrote should do all of the for body then wait for 500ms.

Comment: Would you mind converting that to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @IceRevenge Sure,I did it.

Comment: The fundamental technique behind your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0d9vcwkb/

Answer (score 0):

### Original idea (discarded)

You can create a short function like that:

```
function pause(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Then in any `async` function you can call it like that:

```
async function () {}
    // something happening
    await pause(500);
    // continue
}
```

### The other idea

Now, the code in your question is not complete so this is kind of blind coding but.

So, first of all `setInterval` will be running the whole function every 1 millisecond (actually 4 ms, as this is the minimum in JS). Which means it will run those loops. I decided to focus on the part that was marked by you.

Instead of loop and trying to pause it, I ask that maybe rewriting the loop into function called each half second until condition is met would do?

Also, I move `drawBoard` outside

```
setInterval(async () => {
// ^^^^^^^^ <-- this should probably go
    population.createNewGeneration();
    console.log(i, population.avgFitness);

    let bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns; //Array of boards  

    function tick(turn = 0) {
        let board = bestGameTurns[turn];

        function drawBoard(board) {
            //Draw the board using p5.js rect()'s
        }

        drawBoard(board);

        // here is "setTimeouted" loop
        if (turn < bestGameTurns.length) {
            setTimeout(tick, 500, turn + 1);
        }
    }

    tick();
}, 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. That's just what I tried in my examples just in a separate function, right?

Comment: you can't pass `setTimeout` time as a a variable

Comment: @Dadboz Why not?

Comment: @Dadboz, could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @IceRevenge, how “bout something like that?

Comment: For animation `window.requestAnimationFrame` could work better.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided should do what you asked for, I could only clean up some parts for you. Explain a bit better what is the problem you are facing.

```
// The function should be defined only once.
function drawBoard(board) { }

async function start() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        population.createNewGeneration();

        const bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns; //Array of boards      
        for (let turn = 0; turn < bestGameTurns.length; turn++) {
            // Don't wait on first iteration
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500 * (turn ? 0 : 1 )));

            drawBoard(bestGameTurns[turn]);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, your suggestions brought me to an idea. I found out that the problem was lying somewhere else. Because javascript only runs on the one thread (I think thats how its called), after we run over one generation, we have to stop that function to let another draw function, which runs every frame, draw the board. After it is drawn, the main function can continue. This is how it looks:

```
let isDrawn = false;
let currentBoard;

async function setup() {    
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        population.createNewGeneration();

        const bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns;
        for (let turn = 0; turn < bestGameTurns.length; turn++) {
            await step(bestGameTurns[turn], turn);
        }
    }
}

function step(board, turn) {
    currentBoard = board;
    isDrawn = false;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        if (isDrawn) resolve();
    }, 500));
}

setTimeout(() => {
    if (currentBoard) {
        drawBoard(currentBoard);
        isDrawn = true;
        currentBoard = undefined;
    }
}, 1);
```

```js
const nrOfCols = 10;
const nrOfRows = 10;
const fieldWidth = 20;
const nodeNrs = [24, 8, 8, 4];
const populationSize = 200;
const mutationRate = 0.01;

let population;
let game;

let isDrawn = false;
let currentBoard;

async function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    population = new PopulationManager(populationSize);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        population.createNewGeneration();

        const bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns;
        for (let turn = 0; turn < bestGameTurns.length; turn++) {
            await step(bestGameTurns[turn]);
        }
    }
}

function step(board) {
    currentBoard = board;
    isDrawn = false;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        if (isDrawn) resolve();
    }, 500));
}

function draw() {
    if (currentBoard) {
        drawBoard(currentBoard);
        isDrawn = true;
        currentBoard = undefined;
    }
}

function drawBoard(board) {
    board.forEach((col, colNr) => {
        col.forEach((field, rowNr) => {
            fill(field.isSnake ? "green" : field.isFruit ? "red" : "black");
            stroke(255);
            rect(colNr*fieldWidth, rowNr*fieldWidth, fieldWidth, fieldWidth);
        });
    });
}

function play(game) {    
    setInterval(() => {
        if (!game.lost) {
            game.nextTurn();
            drawBoard(game.board);
        } else {
            clearInterval(1);
        }
    }, 500);
}
class PopulationManager {
    constructor(populationSize) {
        this.population = createPopulation();

        function createPopulation() {
            let population = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
                let chromosomes = createRandomChromosomes();
                let i = new Individual(chromosomes);
                population.push(i);
            }

            return population;

            function createRandomChromosomes() {
                let arr = [];
                let nrOfChromosomes = calcNrOfChromosomes();

                for (let i = 0; i < nrOfChromosomes; i++)
                    arr.push(Math.random()*2-1);

                return arr;

                function calcNrOfChromosomes() {
                    let nr = 0;

                    for (let i = 0; i < nodeNrs.length - 1; i++)
                        nr += (nodeNrs[i] + 1)*nodeNrs[i + 1];

                    return nr;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    createNewGeneration() {
        let that = this;
        
        getFitnessOfPop();

        this.calcAvgFitness();
        this.findBestIndividual();

        let parents = selection();
        breed(parents);
        
        function getFitnessOfPop() {
            that.population.forEach(iv => {
                iv.fitness = iv.playGame();
            });

            that.population.sort((a, b) => a.fitness - b.fitness);
        }

        function selection() {
            let totalFitness = that.population.map(iv => iv.fitness/*  + 1 */).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
            
            let allParents = [];
            
            for (let i = 0; i < that.population.length/2; i++) { 
                allParents.push(selectRandomParents());  
            }

            return allParents;
            
            function selectRandomParents() {
                let p1, p2;
                do {
                    p1 = selectRandomParent();
                    p2 = selectRandomParent();
                } while (p1 == p2); 
                return [p1, p2];
                
                function selectRandomParent() {
                    let rdm = Math.random()*totalFitness;
                    return that.population.find((iv, i) => {
                        let sum = that.population.filter((iv2, i2) => i2 <= i).map(iv => iv.fitness /* + 1 */).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
                        return rdm <= sum;
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        function breed(allParents) {
            that.population = [];

            allParents.forEach(ps => {
                let childChromosomes = crossOver(ps[0].chromosome, ps[1].chromosome);
                childChromosomes = [mutate(childChromosomes[0]), mutate(childChromosomes[1])];
                
                let child1 = new Individual(childChromosomes[0]);
                let child2 = new Individual(childChromosomes[1]);

                that.population.push(child1);
                that.population.push(child2);
            });

            function crossOver(parent1Chromosome, parent2Chromosome) {
                let crossingPoint = Math.round(Math.random()*parent1Chromosome.length);
                
                let divided1 = divideChromosome(parent1Chromosome);
                let divided2 = divideChromosome(parent2Chromosome);

                let child1Chromosome = divided1[0].concat(divided2[1]);
                let child2Chromosome = divided2[0].concat(divided1[1]);

                return [child1Chromosome, child2Chromosome];
                
                function divideChromosome(chromosome) {
                    let part1 = chromosome.filter((g, i) => i <= crossingPoint);
                    let part2 = chromosome.filter((g, i) => i > crossingPoint);
                    return [part1, part2];
                }
            }

            function mutate(chromosome) {
                chromosome = chromosome.map(g => {
                    if (Math.random() < mutationRate) 
                        return Math.random()*2-1;
                    return g;
                });
                return chromosome;
            }
        }    
    }

    calcAvgFitness() {
        this.avgFitness = this.population.map(iv => iv.fitness).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.population.length;
    }

    findBestIndividual() {
        let bestFitness = -1, bestIndividual;
        
        this.population.forEach(i => {
            if (i.fitness > bestFitness) {
                bestFitness = i.fitness;
                bestIndividual = i;
            }   
        });
        
        this.bestIndividual = bestIndividual;
    }
}
class Individual {
    constructor(chromosome) {
        this.chromosome = chromosome;
        this.fitness = 0;
        
        this.game = createGame();

        function createGame() {
            let weights = convertChromosomeToWeights();
            
            let game = new Game(weights);
            
            return game;
            
            function convertChromosomeToWeights() {
                let weights = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < nodeNrs.length - 1; i++) {
                    let lArr = [];
                    
                    for (let j = 0; j < nodeNrs[i] + 1; j++) {
                        let nArr = [];
                        lArr.push(nArr);
                    } 
                    
                    weights.push(lArr);
                }

                chromosome.forEach((gene, geneIdx) => {
                    let lIdx = -1, minIdx, maxIdx = 0;
                    for (let i = 0; i < nodeNrs.length - 1; i++) {
                        let nr = 0;
                        for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                            nr += (nodeNrs[j] + 1)*nodeNrs[j + 1];

                        if (geneIdx < nr) {
                            lIdx = i;
                            break;
                        }
                        
                        maxIdx = nr;
                        minIdx = maxIdx;
                    }

                    minIdx = maxIdx;

                    let nIdx = -1;
                    for (let i = 0; i < nodeNrs[lIdx] + 1; i++) {
                        let nr = minIdx + nodeNrs[lIdx + 1];;
                        
                        if (geneIdx < nr) {
                            nIdx = i;
                            break;
                        }
                        
                        maxIdx = nr;
                        minIdx = maxIdx;
                    }

                    minIdx = maxIdx;
                    
                    let wIdx = -1;
                    for (let i = 0; i < nodeNrs[lIdx + 1]; i++) {
                        let nr = minIdx + 1;
                        
                        if (geneIdx < nr) {
                            wIdx = i;
                            break;
                        }

                        maxIdx = nr;
                        minIdx = maxIdx;
                    }

                    weights[lIdx][nIdx][wIdx] = gene;
                });

                return weights;
            }
        }
    }

    playGame() {
        while (!this.game.lost) {
            this.game.nextTurn();
        }

        return this.game.score;
    }
}

class Game {
    constructor(weights) {
        let that = this;

        this.chromosome = flattenArray(weights);
        this.nn = new NeuralNetwork(weights);
        
        this.turnNr = 0;
        this.score = 0;
        this.lost = false;

        this.board = createBoard();

        this.snake = new Snake();
        setupSnake();

        this.createFruit();

        this.turns = [JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.board))];

        function createBoard() {
            let board = [];

            for (let colNr = 0; colNr < nrOfCols; colNr++) {
                board[colNr] = [];
                for (let rowNr = 0; rowNr < nrOfRows; rowNr++) {
                    let field = new Field(colNr, rowNr);
                    board[colNr][rowNr] = field;
                }
            }    

            return board;
        }

        function setupSnake() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                that.addToTail([floor(nrOfCols/2) - i, floor(nrOfRows/2)]);

            that.length = that.snake.body.length;
        }

        function flattenArray(arr) {
            let flattened = [];
            flatten(arr);
            return flattened;
            
            function flatten(arr) {
                arr.forEach(e => {
                    if (Array.isArray(e))
                        flatten(e);
                    else
                        flattened.push(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }    

    addToTail(pos) {
        this.snake.body.push(pos);
        this.board[pos[0]][pos[1]].setSnake(true);
    }

    nextTurn() {
        let that = this;

        let direction = findDirection();
        this.moveSnake(direction);

        this.turns.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.board)));
        this.turnNr++;

        checkEat();

        
        function findDirection() {
            let inputValues = [];
            
            for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                let distances = that.snake.look(i, that.board);
                inputValues.push(distances.distToFruit);
                inputValues.push(distances.distToWall);
                inputValues.push(distances.distToBody);
            } 

            let output = that.nn.getOutput(inputValues);

            let probability = -1;
            let direction = -1;
            output.forEach((v, vIdx) => {
                if (v > probability) {
                    probability = v;
                    direction = vIdx;
                }
            });

            return direction;
        }

        function checkEat() {
            let head = that.snake.body[0];
            let headField = that.board[head[0]][head[1]];
            if (headField.isFruit) {
                that.snake.eat();
                that.score++;
                headField.setFruit(false);
                that.createFruit();
            }
        } 
    }

    createFruit() {
        let field;

        do {
            let colNr = floor(random()*nrOfCols);
            let rowNr = floor(random()*nrOfRows);
            field = this.board[colNr][rowNr];
        } while(field.isSnake);

        field.setFruit(true);
    }

    moveSnake(newDirection) {
        let that = this;
        let oldBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(that.snake.body));

        moveTail();
        makeSnakeLonger();
        moveHead();

        function moveTail() {        
            for (let i = oldBody.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
                that.snake.body[i] = oldBody[i - 1];
        }

        function moveHead() {    
            let newHeadPosition = findNewHeadPos();
            
            if (
                newHeadPosition[0] >= nrOfCols || newHeadPosition[0] < 0 || 
                newHeadPosition[1] >= nrOfRows || newHeadPosition[1] < 0
            ) {
                that.lose();
                return;    
            }
                
            
            let newHeadField = that.board[newHeadPosition[0]][newHeadPosition[1]];
            if (newHeadField.isSnake) {
                that.lose();
                return;    
            }

            addNewHeadPos(newHeadPosition);
        }

        function findNewHeadPos() {      
            if (newDirection == 0) { //up
                return [oldBody[0][0], oldBody[0][1] - 1];
            } else if (newDirection == 1) { //right
                return [oldBody[0][0] + 1, oldBody[0][1]];
            } else if (newDirection == 2) { //down
                return [oldBody[0][0], oldBody[0][1] + 1];
            } else if (newDirection == 3) { //left
                return [oldBody[0][0] - 1, oldBody[0][1]];
            }
        }

        function makeSnakeLonger() {            
            if (that.snake.length > that.snake.body.length) {
                that.addToTail(oldBody[oldBody.length - 1]);
            } else {
                removeFromTail(oldBody[oldBody.length - 1]);
            }
        }

        function removeFromTail(pos) {
            that.board[pos[0]][pos[1]].setSnake(false);
        }

        function addNewHeadPos(pos) {
            that.snake.body[0] = pos;
            that.board[pos[0]][pos[1]].setSnake(true);
        }
    }

    lose() {
        this.lost = true;
    }
}
class Field {
    constructor(col, row) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;

        this.isFruit = false;
        this.isSnake = false;
    }

    setFruit(bool) {
        this.isFruit = bool;
    }

    setSnake(bool) {
        this.isSnake = bool;
    }
}

class Snake {
    constructor() {
        this.body = [];
        this.length = 4;
    }

    eat() {
        this.length++;
    }

    look(direction, board) {
        let distances = {distToFruit: 0, distToWall: 0, distToBody: 0};
        let xDiff = getXDiff(direction), yDiff = getYDiff(direction);

        let pos = [this.body[0][0] + xDiff, this.body[0][1] + yDiff];
        let dist = 1;
        
        while (pos[0] > 0 && pos[0] < nrOfRows && pos[1] > 0 && pos[1] < nrOfCols) {
            if (board[pos[0]][pos[1]].isFruit && distances.distToFruit == 0) distances.distToFruit = dist;
            if (board[pos[0]][pos[1]].isSnake && distances.distToBody == 0) distances.distToBody = dist;
            pos[0] += xDiff, pos[1] += yDiff;
            dist++;
        }

        distances.distToWall = dist;
        
        return distances;

        function getXDiff(direction) {
            if (direction == 5 || direction == 6 || direction == 7) return -1;
            else if (direction == 1 || direction == 2 || direction == 3) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        
        function getYDiff(direction) {
            if (direction == 7 || direction == 0 || direction == 1) return -1;
            else if (direction == 3 || direction == 4 || direction == 5) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
class NeuralNetwork {
    constructor(weights) {
        this.layers = createLayers();
        this.layers = addWeights(this.layers, weights);
     
        function createLayers() {
            let layers = [];
            
            let nrOfNodesGlobal;
            nodeNrs.forEach((nrOfNodes, lNr) => {
                nrOfNodesGlobal = nrOfNodes;
                layers[lNr] = [];
                
                for (let i = 0; i < nrOfNodes; i++) {
                    let node = createNode(lNr);
                    layers[lNr][i] = node;
                }   

                if (lNr != nodeNrs.length - 1)
                    layers[lNr].push(new Bias());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            });

            return layers;

            function createNode(lNr) {
                if (lNr == 0) return new InputLayerNode();
                else if (lNr == nrOfNodesGlobal - 1) return new OutputLayerNode();
                else return new HiddenLayerNode();
            }
        }

        function addWeights(layers, weights) {
            for (let lNr = 0; lNr < layers.length - 1; lNr++) {
                let l = layers[lNr];
                l.forEach((n1, nNr) => {
                    for (let n2Nr = 0; n2Nr < layers[lNr+1].length - 1; n2Nr++) { //not including bias of next layer
                        let n2 = layers[lNr+1][n2Nr];
                        let weight = weights[lNr][nNr][n2Nr];
                        let w = new Weight(n1, n2, weight);

                        n1.addWeight(w);
                    }
                });
            }

            return layers;
        }
    }

    getOutput(inputValues) {
        let output = [];

        this.layers[0].forEach((inputNeuron, nNr) => {
            if (nNr != this.layers[0].length - 1)
                inputNeuron.addToInput(inputValues[nNr]);
        });

        this.layers.forEach((l, lNr) => {
            calcOutputs(l);  
            if (lNr != this.layers.length - 1) {
                l.forEach(n => {
                    n.feedForward();
                });
            } else {
                output = l.map(n => n.output);
            }
        });

        return output;

        function calcOutputs(layer) {
            layer.forEach(n => n.output = n.activationFunction(n.summedInput, layer.map(N => N.summedInput)));
        }
    }

    log() {
        console.log(this.weights, this.nodes);
    }
}

class Node {
    constructor() {
        this.weights = [];
        this.summedInput = 0;
    }

    addWeight(w) {
        this.weights.push(w);
    }

    addToInput(input) {
        if (input == NaN)
            console.log("A");
        this.summedInput += input;
    }

    feedForward() {
        this.weights.forEach((w, wNr) => {
            let input = w.weight*this.output;
            w.to.addToInput(input);
        });
    }
}

class Bias extends Node {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.output = 1;
    }

    activationFunction(x, allXs) {
        return x;
    }
}

class InputLayerNode extends Node {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    activationFunction(x, allXs) {
        return x;
    }
}

class HiddenLayerNode extends Node {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    activationFunction(x, allXs) {
        return leakyReLU(x);
    }
}

class OutputLayerNode extends Node {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    activationFunction(x, allXs) {
        return softmax(x, allXs);
    }
}

class Weight {
    constructor(from, to, weight) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    setWeight(newWeight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

function leakyReLU(x) {
    if (x >= 0) return x;
    else return 0.01*x;
}

function softmax(x, allXs) {
    return Math.exp(x) / allXs.map(X => Math.exp(X)).reduce((a, b) => a+b);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's not working that well but a few improvements should make it better...

If you have any suggestions for improvements of the code, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

I tried to fix it into steps as I said in comments,I hope I have no mistake :

```
     let i = 0;
    async function step(bestGameTurns, turn)
    {
      if (turn == bestGameTurns.length)
          return;
        let board = bestGameTurns[turn];
        drawBoard(board);
       let p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => step(bestGameTurns, turn+1), 500));
            await p;
    }

    function drawBoard(board) {
                //Draw the board using p5.js rect()'s
       }

    setInterval(async () => {
        population.createNewGeneration();
        console.log(i, population.avgFitness);

        let bestGameTurns = population.bestIndividual.game.turns; //Array of boards  
        step(bestGameTurns, 0);

        i++;
    }, 1);
```

Comment: In the line "step(bestGameTurns, 0)", I think 0 should be i

Comment: That doesn't even compile.

Comment: Based on your own code in for loop you started from 0 ( for turn variable).

Comment: I think it shows the general idea of how it should be done. Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene the core task switching of Windows OS is working with this pattern

Comment: @melpomene why do you think so. I am pretty sure that this solution will work. Give me a minute and I'll try it out.

Comment: @nAviD You also have to remove the closing curly bracket in the third last line... then it will hopefully compile

Comment: @IceRevenge I don't think nAviD knows what `await` does.

Comment: @IceRevenge I said I may have mistakes.

Comment: @melpomene could you explain us what you think await  does. I think it should work  fine there...

Comment: @IceRevenge The first syntax error is about using `await` outside of an `async` function. That's not just a typo; that to me indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what `await` does. The whole manual conversion of a loop into a series of chained callbacks is what `await` / `async` were designed to replace. In other words, if you fix the issues with this code, it does the same thing as your original code.

Comment: @melpomene I know what await does and I can write the whole code without Promise ,async and await. I just wanted to use his code.

Comment: Of course it's possible to write this code without `async` / `await`, but why? What's the point?

Comment: A solution? To what problem?

Comment: @melpomene the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196445/discussion-between-melpomene-and-navid).

Comment: Sorry guys, don't have 20 reputation so if you come to a good answer, please write me. 

@nAviD One question about your code... why is the promise you create never resolved?